# “macOS needs to repair your library” error loop on Mojave upgrade

Tags: macos, upgrade, permission, error, library

I’ve been having trouble fixing the “macOS needs to repair your library” loop for the past couple of days and I’m running out of options. The message pops up over and over again, no matter what I do.

[image]

I’ve gone as far as typing a command in Terminal (recovery mode) which Apple support sent me (the diskutil resetuserpermissions, except longer).

I found some other commands online but I’m not sure what they do and that’s why I haven’t tried them, can anybody help me?

Other commands I’ve found:
`resetpassword` (confused as to WHICH password it’ll reset)
and

`sudo chown -R <user> ~/Library`

`sudo chgrp -R <groupname> ~/Library` (found on this website)

This last one the user said I should get it by running `id -u` for user and `id -g` for groups, but as I am not the tiniest bit familiar with programming, I wonder if he meant I should replace “user” for id -u and same thing for groups??

Please help as I am desperate and Apple support’s solutions haven’t helped me so far!!

Comment: hi, did you try  to log in as different user

Comment: yes, I’ve tried all the primary options (e.g. logging in ss different user, restarting the computer, FirstAid, etc) that’s why now the last option seems to be typing commands on Terminal ( on recovery mode ).

Comment: can we have a screen shot of the error message ! did you release the SIP inhibitor ? can we have some console logs to see what is going on

Comment: I tried uploading a picture but it won’t load. However if you type “macOS needs to repair your library loop” on google images the first few pictures that have a “User Name” and “Password” with a lock next to it, that is exactly what it looks like.

Comment: I’ve been thinking of Re-installing the new OS Mojave, but I’m afraid it’ll worsen my problem because I have little memory.

Comment: that you do not know how to upload a picture here is bit worrisome.  did you try `sudo chown -R <user> ~/Library`  replace the <user> with your user name and without <>

Comment: I know how to do it and tried it, it just wouldn’t load. And no, I haven’t tried that yet, but what do I put on the <groups> bit? My user name again?

Comment: You get the your username by running:

`id -u`

You get your group by running:

`id -g` as result you will get a number, use that in the comands

Comment: thank you for being so helpful so far! I will try and give you an update

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

That’s the link that should help. Worked for me.  I’d been frustrated by this problem for weeks.  Disk utility repair was not good enough. 
But resetting user permissions as per above link did the trick.

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: Most recent known-good snapshot of https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538 via web.archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20200404130045/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538